# Assign a variable to a string of text that is between a certain delimiters Ex. “|” using Java

Tags: java, regex, indexing

I have a string that I want to break down and assign different part of this string to different variables.

```
String: 
String str ="NAME=Mike|Phone=555.555.555| address 298 Stack overflow drive";

To Extract the Name:
int startName = str.indexOf("=");
int endName = str.indexOf("|");
String name = str.substring(startName +1 , endName ).trim();

But I can't extract the phone number: 
int startPhone = arg.indexOf("|Phone");
int endPhone = arg.indexOf("|");
String sip = arg.substring(startPhone + 7, endPhone).trim();
```

Now how can I extract the phone number that is between delimiter "|". 
Also, is there a different way to extract the name using the between delimiter "=" & the first "|"

Comment: Why not split around `|`, with `str.split(\\|)`?

Comment: @Tunaki - Then he will have to split on `=` again. :)

Comment: Try this `(?<=\|Phone=)([\d.]+)(?=|)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on both = and | at the same time, and then pick the non-label parts

```
String delimiters = "[=\\|]";
String[] splitted = str.split(delimiters);
String name = splitted[1];
String phone = splitted[3];
```

Note that his code assumes that the input is formatted exactly as you posted. You may want to check for whitespace and other irregularities.

Answer (score -2):

```
String[] details = str.split("|");
String namePart = details[0]; 
String phonePart = details[1]; 
String addressPart = details[2];
String name = namePart.substring(namePart.indexOf("=") + 1).trim();
String phone = phonePart.substring(phonePart.indexOf("=") + 1).trim();
String address = addressPart.trim();
```

I hope this could help.